# .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2, mod-rewrite

Надо превратить такую ссылку

```
index.php?route=module/brainyfilter/filter&bfilter=f1:1&page=2
```

вот в такую:

```
/man/?page=2
```

или

```
/man/2
```

В данном случае f1:1 - это man

И кое-что другое. Ссылка вида:

```
index.php?route=module/brainyfilter/filter&bfilter=m0:8,57;f1:1;&page=2
```

f1:1 как и в прошлом примере заменяется на man, а вот эта конструкция

```
m0:8,57;
```

должна разбиваться на m0:[id],[id]
количество id от 0 до бесконечности

Хотелось бы превратить второй пример в нечто подобное

```
man/[id]/[id]/?page=2
```

или

```
man/[id]/[id]/2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первую задачу можно решить следующим образом:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=module/brainyfilter/filter&bfilter=f1:1&page=(.*)
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /man/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Здесь идёт перенаправление на адрес вида `/man/2`. Чтобы перенаправлять на адреса вида `/man/?page=2` последнюю строку нужно изменить:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /man/?page=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Со второй задачей сложнее. Не уверен, что её можно решить средствами *mod_rewrite*.

**UPDATE 1**

Как выяснилось из обсуждения в комментариях, нужна обратная задача. Вот решение для первого варианта:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^man/(.+) index.php?route=module/brainyfilter/filter&bfilter=f1:1&page=$1 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.+)$
RewriteRule .* index.php?route=module/brainyfilter/filter&bfilter=f1:1&page=%1 [L,R=302]
```

Второй же вариант также, ИМХО, не решаем с помощью `mod_rewrite`.

**UPDATE 2**

А вот я и неправ! Второй вариант тоже можно решить. Сложно, но можно. Вот пример файла, который делает все необходимые перенаправления адресов вида `/man/id1/.../idN`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !page=
RewriteRule ^man/(.*?)([^\/]+)$ /man/$1?route=module/brainyfilter/filter&bfilter=f1:1&page=$2 [R=303,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &bfilter=f1:1&page=(.+)
RewriteRule ^man/([^\/]+)(.*) /man$2?route=module/brainyfilter/filter&bfilter=m0:$1;f1:1&page=%1 [R=303,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &bfilter=m0:(.+);f1:1&page=(.+)
RewriteRule ^man/([^\/]+)(.*) /man$2?route=module/brainyfilter/filter&bfilter=m0:%1,$1;f1:1&page=%2 [R=303,L,NE]
```

Comment: Сработало, только теперь page не считается GET параметром. http://take.ms/bRYAr

Comment: проблема в следующем: для того, чтобы страница по адресу /index.php?route=module/brainyfilter/filter&bfilter=f1:1 открывалась как /man, было добавлено правильно RewriteRule ^man/(.*) /index.php?route=module/brainyfilter/filter&bfilter=f1:1 [L] Видимо, это правильно и срабатывает каждый раз, не отображая get параметр page

Comment: есть страница site.ru/index.php?route=module/brainyfilter/filter&bfilter=f1:1, она должна открываться по адресу site.ru/man/, на этой странице есть пагинация, исходно - site.ru/index.php?route=module/brainyfilter/filter&bfilter=f1:1&page=1, она должна открываться по адресу site.ru/man/1/

Comment: @morganchees Дополнил ответ решением второго варианта.